Is there a way to compare a drawing with an SVG in React Native Skia?
I'm making an app where you need to draw a given SVG above, in Expo, React Native. Is there a way to compare the SkPath array with my svg?
Here is the component I use for my drawing (most of the code for this component is from SO):
export default function DrawingBoard() {
    const [paths, setPaths] = useState<SkPath[]>([]);

    const onDrawingStart = useCallback((touchInfo: TouchInfo) => {
        setPaths((old) => {
            const { x, y } = touchInfo;
            const newPath = Skia.Path.Make();
            newPath.moveTo(x, y);
            return [...old, newPath];
        });
    }, []);

    const onDrawingActive = useCallback((touchInfo: TouchInfo) => {
        setPaths((currentPaths) => {
            const { x, y } = touchInfo;
            const currentPath = currentPaths[currentPaths.length - 1];
            const lastPoint = currentPath.getLastPt();
            const xMid = (lastPoint.x + x) / 2;
            const yMid = (lastPoint.y + y) / 2;

            currentPath.quadTo(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y, xMid, yMid);
            return [...currentPaths.slice(0, currentPaths.length - 1), currentPath];
        });
    }, []);

    const touchHandler = useTouchHandler(
        {
            onActive: onDrawingActive,
            onStart: onDrawingStart,
        },
        [onDrawingActive, onDrawingStart]
    );

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }} >
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", gap: 5 }} >
                <Button title="Clear" onPress={() => { setPaths([]) }} />
                <Button title="Undo" onPress={() => { setPaths(r => r.slice(0, -1)) }} />
            </View>
            <Canvas style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'lightgray' }}
                onTouch={touchHandler}
            >
                {paths.map((path, index) => (
                    <Path
                        key={index}
                        path={path}
                        color={"black"}
                        style={"stroke"}
                        strokeWidth={2}
                    />
                ))}
            </Canvas>
        </View>
    );
}

And here is the component that displays the SVG I have.
export default function ({ prompt }: Props) {
    const Entry = Object.entries(Index).find(([key]) => key === prompt)
    const Code = Entry && Entry[1][0] || null
    const svg = useSVG(`some link that returns SVG`)

    if (svg) {
        return (
            <Canvas style={{ width: 109, height: 109, alignSelf: 'center' }}>
                <ImageSVG svg={svg} />
            </Canvas>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <Text>
                Oops.
            </Text>
        )
    }
}

Here is the TabComponent:
const ListItem = ({ item, onPress }: ListItemProps) => {
    return (
        <Pressable
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            key={item}
            onPress={onPress}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 30, textAlign: 'center' }}>{item}</Text>
        </Pressable>
    )
}

export default function TabTwoScreen() {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState<string>()
    const data = Object.keys(Index).slice(85)

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 10 }}>
            <FlatList
                numColumns={3}
                style={{ maxHeight: 256 }}
                data={data}
                renderItem={(item) =>
                    <ListItem item={item.item} onPress={() => { setSelected(item.item) }} />
                }
                keyExtractor={item => item}
            />
            {
                selected &&
                <>
                    <Display prompt={selected} />
                    <DrawingBoard />
                </>
            }
        </View>
    );
}

I've read the docs for RN Skia but couldn't find any way to convert the paths into an SVG or SVG into paths array. And I have no idea about what other ways do I have.
